# hbase client running output "Usage: mapfile infile outfile"

Tags: apache2, java, eclipse

I have made a simple client application in java for Hbase to connect with it and show results for some queries e.g list, scan etc.

But When i run my application in eclispe, there are no errors but output is only

USAGE: MapFile inFile OutFile.

Why this message is appearing and what is its meaning. Hbase is running so I think its not a problem of connectivity atleast.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above problem was solved by doing following things.

In order to run application,follow

1. Run configuration

2.In main class tab, search for your project main class it should be something like package_name.main_class

3. Now run, it will solve the above problem